# Kafka consumer exception handling

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I need to send a message that the data is invalid in the following type if invalid data comes

```
{
    "correlationId": "6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00CF4FC964FF",
    "apiVersion": "1.0",
    "eventCode": "task_started",
    "event_time": "2020-04-25 16:48:33",    
    "sender": "wrs2_tc5_prod",
    "body": {
        "trigger_correlationId": "6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00CF4FC964FF",
        "store_sap": "2006"
    }
}
```

There is this `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` class that accepts `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`, but in case of an error, I need to determine the type of error, which includes three types (`INVALID ATTRIBUTE, UNDEFINED ERROR, INVALID FORMAT`), and send a message to a specific topic.

How can I implement this logic?

Comment: Where exactly does your consumer "fail"? If you're getting valid JSON, then you don't need deserialization exception handling, so just check the individual fields and if it matches some condition you've set, then produce to another topic

Answer (score 1):

Use an `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer together with a custom destination resolver in the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`.